# react Carousel Type for components

Tags: reactjs, loops, infinite-loop

i would like to make a component in react that render different components like a carousel,
i would like to loop infinitely through an array to render the new components every 5 secondes:

```
import cenLogo from "./images/CKBRlogo.jpg";
import "./index.css";
import "./App.css";
import Weather from "./components/weather";
import SnowMan from "./components/snowMan";




function App() {
 
  const toShow = [<Weather/>, <SnowMan/>]


  
  return (
    
    <div className="App bg-gray-200 h-screen w-full p-6 font-sansImported ">
      <div className="h-2/3">
        <img alt="mainLogo" src={cenLogo} className=" rounded mx-auto" height="10" width="90" />
        <h1 className="text-centaraGold text-5xl mt-6 mb-6">What is up today?</h1>
          {toShow[0]}
      {/*THIS IS WERE I WANT TO LOOP INDEFINITELY THROUGH THE ARRAY*/}
        <footer className="fixed bottom-0 w-screen text-gray-500 text-xs">
        <p >Made by Florent Hebinger</p>
        </footer>
      
     
      </div>
      
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Or is there a way to do this with react router ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem above without getting an error.

I use useEffect() ant setInterval

```
useEffect(() => {
const carousel = setInterval(() => {
  comp === toShow.length - 1
    ? setcomp(0) && clearInterval(carousel)
    : setcomp(comp + 1);
}, 7000);
return () => {
  clearInterval(carousel);
};
```

And i use react-fade-in for the transition part.